# Use azure-eventhubs-clients to connect to QPid AMQP 1.0 broker?

Tags: azure, amqp, azure-eventhub, qpid

If I leverage https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs for client connectivity to Azure EventHubs in the cloud, can I also use this same client code to connect to a QPid AMQP 1.0 broker?

I can't find any detailed documentation on how the various part of an eventhubs client connection-string is interpreted but I substituted a standard (amqp://ip:port) address as the Endpoint port of the connection string but keep getting a com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.TimeoutException.

I'm using the [Java ReceiveTest.java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-java/blob/e6413d059471d75224a62df89251c5dfd331f5e2/azure-eventhubs/src/test/java/com/microsoft/azure/eventhubs/sendrecv/ReceiveTest.java) from the unit tests and a QPid broker with the following amqp address: `amqps://192.168.56.199:5672` I found that the connection-string parser simply failed if I used just that, but am having a hard time understanding what is the right connection-string to simply point at an AMQP broker.

[edit:]
So my connection-string is (provisionally) the following which at least passes the parser and gets the library to at least try to connect:

> `Endpoint=amqps://192.168.56.199:5672/example;SharedAccessKey‌​Name=managed-policy;‌​SharedAccessKey=p7S3‌​kSqN/<snip key>=;EntityPath=<hub-name>`

Comment: There's not really enough info to go on here, provide more details like code etc

Comment: Ok, added more info to reproduce it; hope that was enough.